# RREF not defined in Julia

Tags: julia, linear-algebra

I just install Julia, along with LinearAlgebra package.

When I type

```
A = [1 2 3 4; 4 5 6 7]
rref(A)
```

My terminal said

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: rref not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[22]:1
```

I am sort of confused. Do I need to install certain package in order to use reef function?

Comment: Where did you read that there would be a function called that (asking since there might be outdated information out there that should be updated)?

Answer (score 3):

There s no such function in the `LinearAlgebra` package. There used to be a long time ago, but is has since moved to https://github.com/blegat/RowEchelon.jl.